# Serverless resource deployement status “CREATE_IN_PROGRESS”

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I created a serverless resource for elasticsearch with all necessary policies. We are using seed to build and deploy to cloudformation stacks. The policy is created, elasticsearch domain creation is in process and the policy is also attached to the domain. But it takes very long time and even waiting an hour or so, the status is still “CREATE_IN_PROGRESS”. The process doesn't complete.

I have tried without policies, which creates the elasticsearch domain without taking so much time.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: Serverless Resource

```
Resources:
ElasticSearchInstance:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      ElasticsearchVersion: 7.4
      DomainName: ${self:custom.stage}-domainName
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: true
        VolumeType: gp2
        VolumeSize: 10
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
        InstanceType: "t2.small.elasticsearch"
        InstanceCount: 1
        DedicatedMasterEnabled: false
        ZoneAwarenessEnabled: false
      CognitoOptions:
          Enabled: true
          IdentityPoolId:
            Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
          RoleArn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [ElasticSearchLambdaServiceRole, Arn]
          UserPoolId:
            Ref: CognitoUserPool

  ElasticSearchLambdaServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: ElasticSearchLambdaServiceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - es.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ElasticSearchAccessPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              # # Policy same as "AmazonESCognitoAccess"
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool"
                  - "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient"
                  - "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth"
                  - "cognito-idp:AdminUserGlobalSignOut"
                  - "cognito-idp:ListUserPoolClients"
                  - "cognito-identity:DescribeIdentityPool"
                  - "cognito-identity:SetIdentityPoolRoles"
                  - "cognito-identity:GetIdentityPoolRoles"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: "iam:PassRole"
                Resource: "*"
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    "iam:PassedToService": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: "es:ESHttpGet"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource:
                  - 'Fn::Join':
                      - ':'
                      -
                        - 'arn:aws:logs'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                        - 'log-group~:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "es:*"
                Resource:
                  - 'Fn::Join':
                      - ''
                      -
                        - 'arn:aws:es:'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - ':'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                        - ':domain/'
                        - "${self:custom.stage}-domainName"
                        - '/*'
```

Comment: Do you have a custom resource?  Custom resources will hang if not done correctly.

Comment: When you setup same ES domain manually in console (same VPC, same subnets, same policies, .... same everything), does it work normally?

Comment: @TimBassett I have created elasticsearch domain from serverless without policies and that worked. With policies everything is created except domain creation completion. Not sure where the error is.

Comment: @Marcin I have a working elasticdomain which was created manually with default vpc. I copied the policies from that domain.